# JavaScriptでID、クラス等で指定されていないAタグのhrefを実行する方法はありませんか？

Tags: javascript

JavaScript初心者のため、基本的な質問となっていたら申し訳ございません。
今、私は既存のWebサイトの操作を自動化するマクロを作成しております。
自動化マクロの作成に当たって、JavaScriptを用いて現在作業を進めているのですが、
その中でClassやIDを持たないAタグを指定し、その先のリンクへ遷移する必要がある場面に直面しています。
何かいい手段等ありますでしょうか？

Comment: マクロをどのような形で記録しているのかわかりませんが、何番目のリンクというのが分かっていれば、[document.links](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/links)を使って配列の形でアクセスできます。

Comment: 解決したなら承認して頂けるとありがたいです

Answer (score 7):

jQueryを使用するのが一番楽だと思います。
セレクタを使用して取得できます。
おそらく何かの配下になると思われるので、下記のような感じでしょうか。
親要素のID等も分からない場合は、下記を応用してネストしていくのが良いと思います。

```
$("#親要素のID").find("a").each(function(){
    alert( $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

■JavaScriptのみで行う場合

```
// どこでもいいからAタグの中身を取得したい場合
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    alert(tags[i].getAttribute("href"))
}


// 親ID配下のAタグを取得する場合
var oya = document.getElementById(親のID)
var tags = oya.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    alert(tags[i].getAttribute("href"))
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
記載してくださったコードを使わせていただきます！

Answer (score 5):

@SSDevさんので解決済みのようなので別の書き方の参考定時だけ。

モダンブラウザが前提であれば、jQueryなしでも書きやすいですね。

#### Ex: `https://google` から始まるリンクのみの抽出

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="https://google"]');
for(const link of links){
  console.log(link);
}
```